# Lua table.foreach missing

Tags: foreach, lua, lua-table

I used https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo quite a lot to quickly hack together some scripts and test if they actually work. But today I stumpled across something that is very strange.

Testing this code

```
local t = {}
local threshold = 3
local counter = 0
t["1"] = true
t["2"] = true
t["3"] = false
t["4"] = true

table.foreach(t, print)
table.foreach(
  t,
  function(k,v)
    if v then
      counter = counter + 1
    end
  end
)
print(counter)
```

gave me this error message

> input:9: attempt to call a nil value (field 'foreach')

so I tried running

```
for k,v in pairs(table) do
  print(k,v)
end
```

resulting in this output

```
concat  function: 0x42be90
remove  function: 0x42bca0
sort    function: 0x42ba50
move    function: 0x42baf0
insert  function: 0x42bda0
unpack  function: 0x42b2a0
pack    function: 0x42b3a0
```

Since it's about a year ago I last used this site to test my code I can't really tell when there was a change. Or if there was a change. I am very sure last time I used that site I used the `table.foreach` function. But now it does not work.
I also checked the changelog in case there was a change I missed but https://www.lua.org/versions.html does not show any change past June 2020 with version 5.4

May someone tell me where I messed up or what I am missing?

Comment: `table.foreach` was deprecated in Lua 5.1 and removed in Lua 5.2. The online Lua demo always runs the latest release of Lua, which is Lua 5.4.4.

Comment: since you asked for the change: https://github.com/lua/lua/commit/5b33e398557d7afad4a916bb483e9894e4b9b3d4 it has been removed nearly 13 years ago

Comment: ok that is even more strange sincei i clearly remember using table.foreach last time i tested some of my code. and on top of that the page on http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial last edited 2017 contains table.foreach but 5.2 is from 2015

Comment: is there a replacement for table.foreach?

Comment: But your linked tutorial is referencing the 5.1 reference.

Comment: A replacement is basically `pairs`, and if you really need a similar function (e.g. for compatibility) you can write it yourself (which internally just uses pairs again)